# How to import a range of lines in a file in python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a set of data files where there is a bunch of header information followed by columns of values that I want to store in a data structure using python.

ie:

%multiple lines of header information

%column headers

dataincol1   dataincol2    dataincol3

....
etc

The starting point and length of the columns are not the same from file to file, but the column headers are the same.  I can do this if I use a flag (ie, found the column headers, set flag and import the rest of the lines using the readline call) but I wanted to know if there was something more elegant.

Comment: That is reading lines of the file, not "importing" them.

Comment: @Jen What do you call _"set flag"_ ? What criterion to find the column headers line ? What kind of data structure : tuple, list, deque, dictionary... what will be the more convenient for the rest of the app ?

Answer (score 0):

A flag is just fine. However one other way is to stop the iteration and continue it in another loop:

```
iter = open(filename).__iter__()
for line in iter: # process all lines until column header
    if line == "COLUMN_HEADERS": # or whatever
         break
for line in iter: # process all subsequent lines
    process_line(line)
```